# cross out the text in the section title

Tags: soul, strikeout

It seems that `\st{}` for crossing out a text (strike through) doesn't work on the section title. For example, this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul,color}
\begin{document}
\section{\st{Motivation}}\label{sec:theproblem}
In this section, we are going to explain the detail and you will see...
\end{document}
```

fails while it works fine with the body text

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul,color}
\begin{document}
\section{Motivation}\label{sec:theproblem}
In this section, we are going to \st{explain the detail} and you will see...
\end{document}
```

BTW, yes the `soul` package is included :)

**UPDATE**

**UPDATE**

Using `\protect\st` works fine but the bug is, if you add `\usepackage{hyperref}`, you will get this error

```
! Argument of \let has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.5 \section{\protect\st{Motivation}}
                                     \label{sec:theproblem}
?
```

The problem has been addressed by *Christian Hupfer* in his answer.

Comment: you haven't provided a usable test file but `\protect\st` probably works

Comment: your code work very good for me

Comment: Same here.  Perhaps it's time to update your packages.

Comment: What is the version of `soul`? The latest seems to be from **2003/11/17**

Comment: Let start with this example and add your packages one by one to find the problem (may be)

Comment: Yes. That small example works for me either, but in my bigger document, I get that error. if I remove `\protect\st` then it is fine! I will post a screen shot

Comment: @mahmood: I think, a screen shot is not really helpful. Your code, at least to the position where it stops would be really nice ;-)

Comment: the screenshot is not useful as it does not relate to the code you hav eposted

Comment: Hey guys.... if you add `\usepackage{hyperref}` for other purposes, you will see that the \protect fails!! This is the bug

Comment: If you had made a test file using hyperref you would have saved people a lot of trouble. It is not a bug see `\texorpdfstring{TEXstring }{PDFstring }` in the hyperref documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Early version of this solution*

> The specific behaviour of the `sectioning` commands require special
>   treatment for the content to be designed as title of chapters etc, in
>   this case for the `\st` command from the `soul` package. It must be
>   protected, i.e. preceeded by a `\protect`.

**Edit**

I just tested: The `\st` macro is already robust. `\protect` is not really needed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\protect\st{This is crossed-out}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit Number Two**

If `hyperref` is used, this runs into the typical problem with the bookmarks and hyperlinks. Use `\texorpdfstring` to get around for such a woe ;-)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\texorpdfstring{\st{This is crossed-out}}{This is not crossed out}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @mahmood: Your example document works for me without problems (the one with `\section{\protect\st....}`

Comment: Can you add `\usepackage{hyperref}` and see if your examples is still working?

Comment: @mahmood: See my updated answer

Comment: If you want to add command like `\setstcolor`, you have to use `\protect\setstcolor{red}\texorpdfstring{\st{tex}}{pdf}}`

Comment: This solution in Edit #2 works for highlighting too!!! That is the only thing works to highlight the subsubsection for me. I used `\subsubsection{\texorpdfstring{\hl{This is highlighted}}{This is not highlighted}}`

Answer (score 1):

In user31729's solution the uncrossed text ("This is not crossed out") does not appear in the title or the ToC.  If both soul and plain text are required, such as to show a correction, the following code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{\texorpdfstring{\st{Old}{New}}{}}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Sample output

[image: Image showing crossed and uncrossed text]